# Mutalyzer py.test fails with python-magic error

Tags: python, anaconda, centos6

I am trying to install [mutalyzer 2.0.14](https://github.com/mutalyzer/mutalyzer) on `Centos 6.7` using `Anaconda Python 2.7` as per [these](http://mutalyzer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) instructions.

My install goes fine, but I get a series of fails when I attempt to run the `py.test` suite.

My suspicion is that there is a version clash between the OS' version of `libmagic` and the python2.7 package, `python-magic`.

I'd be very interested if anyone could explain what is going on here or better still suggest a fix for this problem.

My libmagic installs:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep 'file-'
file-libs-5.04-21.el6.x86_64
file-5.04-21.el6.x86_64
file-devel-5.04-21.el6.x86_64
```

Corresponding Python packages:

```
$ source activate  py27
discarding /opt/anaconda2/bin from PATH
prepending /opt/anaconda2/envs/py27/bin to PATH
(py27) $ pip list | grep magic 
Magic-file-extensions (0.2, /home/chris.guest/temp/mutalyzer/src/magic-file-extensions)
python-magic (0.4.10)
```

py.test begins like this:

```
# py.test
======================================================= test session starts =======================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.11, pytest-2.8.2, py-1.4.30, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /home/chris.guest/temp/mutalyzer, inifile: 
collected 610 items / 3 errors 

tests/test_backtranslator.py ......
tests/test_base.py .
tests/test_crossmap.py .......................
tests/test_grammar.py ........................................................................................
tests/test_mapping.py ..............................
tests/test_migrations.py .
tests/test_mutator.py ................................................................................................................................................................
tests/test_ncbi.py ............................................................................................................
tests/test_parsers_genbank.py ..........
```

And finishes with a lot of errors. Many tests failing because of `undefined symbol: magic_list`:

```
_________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_batch_unicode[sqlite://] _________________________________________

    @pytest.fixture
    def website():
>       return create_app().test_client()

tests/test_website.py:29: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
mutalyzer/website/__init__.py:35: in create_app
    from mutalyzer.website.views import website
mutalyzer/website/views.py:26: in <module>
    from mutalyzer import (announce, backtranslator, File, Retriever, Scheduler,
mutalyzer/File.py:23: in <module>
    import magic           # open(), MAGIC_MIME, MAGIC_NONE
src/magic-file-extensions/magic.py:94: in <module>
    _list = _libraries['magic'].magic_list
/opt/anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py:378: in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <CDLL 'libmagic.so.1', handle 160cc50 at 7f23b97340d0>, name_or_ordinal = 'magic_list'

    def __getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal):
>       func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
E       AttributeError: /usr/lib64/libmagic.so.1: undefined symbol: magic_list

/opt/anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py:383: AttributeError
______________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_batch_unicode_email[sqlite://] ______________________________________

    @pytest.fixture
    def website():
>       return create_app().test_client()

tests/test_website.py:29: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
mutalyzer/website/__init__.py:35: in create_app
    from mutalyzer.website.views import website
mutalyzer/website/views.py:26: in <module>
    from mutalyzer import (announce, backtranslator, File, Retriever, Scheduler,
mutalyzer/File.py:23: in <module>
    import magic           # open(), MAGIC_MIME, MAGIC_NONE
src/magic-file-extensions/magic.py:94: in <module>
    _list = _libraries['magic'].magic_list
/opt/anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py:378: in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <CDLL 'libmagic.so.1', handle 160cc50 at 7f23b984ef50>, name_or_ordinal = 'magic_list'

    def __getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal):
>       func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
E       AttributeError: /usr/lib64/libmagic.so.1: undefined symbol: magic_list

/opt/anaconda2/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py:383: AttributeError
============================================== 548 passed, 65 error in 41.42 seconds ==============================================
(py27)[root@localhost mutalyzer]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of magiclib that is packaged with Centos 6.7 is missing the `magic_list` function.

I was able to make this patch to `src/magic-file-extensions/magic.py` so that py.test runs without error.

```
$ diff -u src/magic-file-extensions/magic.old.py src/magic-file-extensions/magic.py
--- src/magic-file-extensions/magic.old.py  2015-12-31 14:04:50.769635453 +1100
+++ src/magic-file-extensions/magic.py  2016-01-11 15:17:49.987270845 +1100
@@ -91,9 +91,13 @@
 _check.restype = c_int
 _check.argtypes = [magic_t, c_char_p]

-_list = _libraries['magic'].magic_list
-_list.restype = c_int
-_list.argtypes = [magic_t, c_char_p]
+try:
+    _list = _libraries['magic'].magic_list
+    _list.restype = c_int
+    _list.argtypes = [magic_t, c_char_p]
+except AttributeError, e:
+    _list = None
+    

 _errno = _libraries['magic'].magic_errno
 _errno.restype = c_int
```

While the immediate `AttributeError` is handled with this patch, the `Magic.list` method in `src/magic-file-extensions/magic.py` will still fail if it is called. This is not an immediate issue as it doesn't appear to be called within the `mutalyzer` codebase.

Comment: @MartijnVermaat please feel free to add this patch to the `mutalyzer` code base if you think it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We have one earlier report of a user trying to install Mutalyzer on CentOS 6 and they too ran into troubles with libmagic. I don't think this was resolved, other than them switching to CentOS 7.

Unfortunately we have very limited resources and Debian being the only OS we use ourselves that's all we can realistically support. Of course we would be happy to accept patches or documentation updates :)

Thanks for using Mutalyzer!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10739374)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to leave this as a comment but was disallowed because it requires a certain amount of reputation. Also, as me being the main maintainer of the software referenced (Mutalyzer), this is the most authoritive answer you will get on how to run Mutalyzer: upgrade to CentOS 7 or run it on Debian. I believe that provides *a* fix to the problem, which is what @ChrisGuest asked for. If the question was more general on how to use python-magic on CentOS 6 I would agree I have no answer to that.

Comment: @MartijnVermaat thanks for responding to this. I will leave the question open for a while and see if anyone else has a response to this.
If all else fails I can probably get a Centos7 box commissioned.

Comment: @ChrisGuest I might add that we also have an [Ansible playbook](https://github.com/mutalyzer/ansible-role-mutalyzer) to automate deployment of Mutalyzer in a production environment. This is more tightly coupled to Debian 8 specifically though (but comes with a [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) recipe for quick tests). And of course feel free to contact us (see the Contact link on the Mutalyzer website).

Comment: @ChrisGuest Thanks, I made Mutalyzer installable on CentOS 6 following your suggestion above (hopefully, didn't test). (Couldn't comment on your answer).